# Can a byte[] buffer for a MemoryStream have variable size?

Tags: c#, serialization, memorystream, base-class-library

I'm serializing an object to a `byte[]` using `MemoryStream`:

```
byte[] serialized = new byte[1000];
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(serialized))
    using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, stuffToSerialize);
```

is there any way I can set `'serialized'` to grow according to the size of the `stuffToSerialize`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parameterless constructor `new MemoryStream()` uses one.

Then serialise into it, and then when you need the `byte[]` call `ToArray()` which creates a copy of whatever length of the buffer was actually used (the internal buffer will generally have some growing space at any point, and that's normally not desirable, `ToArray()` gives you what you actually care about).

At the end of the following code, it will have the same effect as your code, were you able to predict the correct size:

```
byte[] serialized;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
  {
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, stuffToSerialize);
  }
  // Note: you can even call stream.Close here is you are paranoid enough
  // - ToArray/GetBuffer work on disposed MemoryStream objects.
  serialized = stream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm not using it as a buffer for another variable - I'm storing the serialized object in it.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do `textWriter.ToArray()`.

Comment: +1. Note that sample misses necessary Flush call or better yet moving call to ToArray outside of inner using. Updating code...

Comment: Quite right @AlexeiLevenkov an oversight in copying what isn't directly analogous.

Comment: This code won't compile, `new MemoryStream(serialized)` should probably be `new MemoryStream()`.  You can't pass in an uninitialised variable.

Comment: @nicodemus13 exactly right, it was just left by mistake having copy-pasted from the question to then produce the variant for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the constructor that takes a provided existing `byte[]` buffer, then no, because an array once allocated has a fixed size.

The default constructor, as well as any other constructor that does not accept a `byte[]` parameter, will replace the existing buffer with a larger one as needed.  Note that this may complicate things if you use [`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx): if the stream is appended to after calling GetBuffer(), the actual `byte[]` backing the stream may be replaced.  Also note that when calling `GetBuffer()`, the stream data may not begin at index 0 of the returned array!

To get the contents back out, use [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) to get them as a byte array, or [`WriteTo(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto.aspx) to pour the contents of the `MemoryStream` into another stream.

Comment: But then how do I get the bytes out of `'textWriter'`?

Comment: @ispiro The [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) method gets you a byte array, or the [WriteTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto.aspx) method pours the contents into another stream.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do `textWriter.ToArray()`.