# Get one property only of XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I don't have experience with this so perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology.

The scenario is this: I'm serializing a class instance to a file using the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309136/939213 . But at some point I might want to change the class a bit, so I would like to insert an `int` into the file telling the program what version of the class this is.

I tried serializing the int and the class into the same file but discovered that's impossible, so I'm now thinking of having an `int` property in the class for that, and reading that first, in order to know what class should be deserialized.

So how do I read that `int` alone?

EDIT: For example, to read the `myInt` in this:

```
<MyClass xml...> 
    <myInt>10</myInt> 
    <myString>abc</myString> 
</MyClass>
```

Comment: You need to provide some example xml if you want a specific answer, otherwise you can check out [Linq-To-Xml](https://www.google.com/search?q=linq+to+xml+c%23&rlz=1C1DVCC_enUS346&aq=1&oq=linq+to+xml&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for more info.

Comment: @ChuckSavage Thanks. Your comment lead me to an answer. You can convert it to an answer.

Comment: Ok, set it as an answer - glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide some example xml if you want a specific answer, otherwise you can check out [Linq-To-Xml](https://www.google.com/search?q=linq+to+xml+c%23&rlz=1C1DVCC_enUS346&aq=1&oq=linq+to+xml&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

A comment lead me to a solution:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
int answer = (int)xdoc.Descendants("myInt").ToArray()[0];
```